# How to show input after hidden in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have worked with `[hidden]` in Angular to display an input based on the selected value in a select element.

My problem occurs when the input is hidden because of my condition `this.indiceSelectedType !== 0`: When this value becomes `0` the input doesn't appear again despite that it exists in the DOM. So it is not deleted because i didn't use `*ngIf`.

Here is my Html snippet:

```html
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="inputtypeParticipation" class="col-sm-4" style="Font-Weight: Bold;padding-top: 10px;">Type Participation :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <select [(ngModel)]="indiceSelectedType" id="inputtypeParticipation" class="browser-default custom-select mb-3" (change)="showTypePart($event.target.value)">
        <option value="0" selected>Pourcentage</option>
        <option value="1">Gratuit si inférieur ou égale</option>
        <option value="2">Gratuit si supérieur</option>
        <option value="3">Gratuit si le client a un autre produit</option>
        <option value="4">Rang gratuit</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row" id="Pourcentage" [hidden]="this.indiceSelectedType !== 0">
    <label for="inputPourcentage" class="col-sm-4" style="Font-Weight: Bold;white-space: nowrap;">Pourcentage :</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input style="width: 265px;" type="number" class="form-control" id="inputPourcentage">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Notice that I added `(change)` just to test the value of `indiceSelectedType` with `ngModel` and it changes indeed when I select another option in the select.

Comment: Any reason you're not using `*ngIf`?

Comment: @WillAlexander because ngIf delete the element from the DOM but i want to hide/show so the best way is with hidden attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few things needs to be changed in your code,

Change `[hidden]="this.indiceSelectedType !== 0"` to `[hidden]="indiceSelectedType != 0"`,

Here remove `this` keyword which will be used only in `TS` file and not in template.

Not equal to should look like this `!=` and not like this `!==` ..

If you want to check for type then use like this `'0'` and it should look like `indiceSelectedType !== '0'` , because in your code you are trying to compare `string` with `number` using `!==` which is false..

[**Working Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4go5bi)